# Scala pattern match regex

Tags: regex, scala

In my scala program, I want to use a pattern match to test whether there is a valid .csv file in the input path.
path ="\DAP\TestData\test01.csv"
val regex=""".csv$""".r.unanchored

I tried to use the previous regex to match the string, it worked, but when it went to match pattern, it cannot work.

```
path ="\DAP\TestData\test01.csv"
val regex="""\.csv$""".r.unanchored    
path match {
  case regex(type) =>println(s"$type matched")
  case _ =>println("something else happeded")
}
```

I need to successfully print information like ".csv matched".
Could anyone help me with this issue? I m really confused by this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which part of the `path` you want to capture and report. But in any case you'll probably want a capture group in the regex pattern.

```
val path = raw"\DAP\TestData\test01.csv"
val re = """(.*\.csv)$""".r.unanchored
path match {
  case re(typ) => println(s"$typ matched")   //"\DAP\TestData\test01.csv matched"
  case _       => println("something else happened")
}
```

---

You can also use the capture group to capture any one of many different target patterns.

```
val re = ".*\\.((?i:json|xml|csv))$".r
raw"\root\test31.XML" match {
  case re(ext) => println(s"$ext matched")   //"XML matched"
  case _       => println("something else happeded")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
 val regex = """(\.csv)$""".r.unanchored

    path match {
      case regex(fileType) => println(s"$fileType matched")
      case _ => println("something else happeded")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Teena. while I have multiple regex for matching different types of files, like json, xml,csv. So I need to use the pattern to match those regex expressions in the pattern match code block. Is there  a way to do this?

Comment: Hi, @kyandy, I've updated my comment. You just need to modify the regex, have a look.